# Terraform openstack forces new resource

Tags: openstack, terraform

Im trying to deploy some infrastructure via terraform. The first time i run apply it deploys the vm no problem but if i run apply again it wants to run destroy and redeploy the vm even though there has been no changes to the configuration. What i can see from the output this is because of id and network.o.name and im not sure why this is causing an issue

```
resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "test" {
  name            = "test_server"
  image_id        = "image_id"
  flavor_id       = "flavour_id"
  key_pair        = "test"
  security_groups = ["default"]

  network {
    name = "Default Network"
  }
}
```

id:                         "16342cd6-7f26-4a77-9c3f-11c626400f4f" =>  (forces new resource)

network.0.name:             "Default network" => "Default Network" (forces new resource)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not used OpenStack for a long time but it looks like the network name is not case sensitive in OpenStack so your instance is being put in the `Default network` network despite having a different cased network name specified in the configuration (`Default Network`).

Because the [`network.name` attribute is set as `ForceNew`](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-openstack/blob/6faa23cd6d138a0940c788ff9a145d715bf4dbe6/openstack/resource_openstack_compute_instance_v2.go#L129-L134) then Terraform detects the drift between the configuration and the provider and says it needs to create a new resource. Simply updating your configuration to match what the provider is using should be fine in this case.

The normal way to fix this properly in a provider is to use a `DiffSuppresFunc` which makes Terraform ignore the diff between configuration and provider. The `openstack_compute_instance_v2` resource already uses this to [suppress differences in availability zones](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-openstack/blob/6faa23cd6d138a0940c788ff9a145d715bf4dbe6/openstack/resource_openstack_compute_instance_v2.go#L114).